# How to correctly reuse productions in other sorts?

Tags: kframework

I have a syntax:

```
syntax Exp ::= Int | Bool
             | Exp Exp
             > Exp + Exp           [left] 
             > "fun" KVar "->" Exp [binder]
             | "(" Exp ")"         [bracket]
syntax Val ::= Int | Bool | "fun" KVar "->" Exp [binder]
```

where lambda terms `"fun" KVar "->" Exp` are values and expressions. What's the correct way to make `"fun" KVar "->" Exp` part of both `Exp` and `Val`?

I tried creating a new sort `syntax Lambda ::= "fun" KVar "->" Exp` and adding `Lambda` to both `Val` and `Exp`. However, this messes with the priority of `Lambda`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do instead:

```
syntax Exp ::= Val
             | Exp Exp
             | Exp + Exp           [left, add] 
             | "(" Exp ")"         [bracket]
syntax Val ::= Int | Bool | "fun" KVar "->" Exp [binder, fun]
syntax priorities add > fun
```

**EDIT** I've updated my answer to include @dwight.guth's suggestion.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Doesn't this affect the priority of the lambda production?
e.g. `fun x -> x + y` would parse as `(fun x -> x) + y`. Or is this unavoidable?

Comment: You are correct that it affects the relative priorities, but this is why the `syntax priorities` sentence was created. You can do something like:
`syntax Exp ::= Val | Exp Exp | Exp + Exp [left, add] | "(" Exp ")" [bracket] syntax Val ::= Int | Bool | "fun" KVar "->" Exp [binder, fun] syntax priorities add > fun
`

Comment: ah, thanks! So I can add any label inside the square brackets to refer to that production?

Comment: is it possible to define syntax priorities on entire sorts? or must they be on the labels in the square brackets?